# Online note taking / journal application

Tags: linux, web-apps

I'm looking for a tool in which I can write my documentation.
It should protect my entries from prying eyes, but I want to be able to write an entry from where ever I currently am. Plus a fulltext search should be available.

I used Habari for that, but it doesn't work on my new webspace.

It's essential that it's a self-hosted solution, but I don't care about the language it's written in (PHP, Rails, Python, ...). Wordpress, Drupal and the like have a too large functionality and, as such, attack surface for me to use them for this purpose.

I'd also accept a commandline application like hnb or memo, but it'd be nice if the documents were stored encrypted.

In the end, a journal application might fit my needs.

**Note**: http://github.com/grena/gruik is promising. Markdown, Search, lots of JS niceness... It's in an early stadium and would be a solution, if it was a single-user application (or one could somehow prevent new users from signing up).