# Libre Note-taking application with pen support

Tags: offline, note-taking, document-management, drawing, annotation

Usecase:

[image]
<sub>OneNote on Microsoft Surface, text on screenshot is german</sub>

For my university notes I'd like to use a libre note-taking application with text and pen support (very important for, say, diagrams and formulas)

In the past I've used **Drawboard PDF**, **Xodo** and now **OneNote**.
The first two sort of 'work' but they're very buggy and thanks to closed source I can't do a thing about it.

Drawboard PDF and Xodo both use PDF Annotations, which creates a nice interchangeability between PDF Annotators.
OneNote on the other hand stores all the data inside a single .one file (a "section").
It's hard to organize individual lectures when one file is the whole course. The OneNote UI doesn't accommodate creating a separate section for separate lectures.
Besides, the .one format seems utterly stupid sometimes. A newly created empty section sometimes takes up to 11 MB.

[image]

Is there a software that

- support surface pen
- support text insert (no rtf needed!)
- lets me edit on per-file basis (pdf, djvu, ... <sub>format itself doesn't matter as long as it's somewhat shareabe</sub>)
- offline ; not web-based
- doesn't crash every few minutes or so
- (FOSS/libre would be very good in the long term)

---

<sub>for the record, these questions are not duplicates:

- [Application for drawing diagrams freehand and exporting as images on Microsoft Surface with support for the Surface Pen](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/application-for-drawing-diagrams-freehand-and-exporting-as-images-on-microsoft-s)

- [Does Libre Office have an equivalent of OneNote, or is there another alternative?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511629/does-libre-office-have-an-equivalent-of-onenote-or-is-there-another-alternative)

- [Online note taking / journal application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/online-note-taking-journal-application)</sub>

Comment: I haven't used any of them, so am not proposing as an answer, but https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-onenote/ suggests a number of possibilities. The big 'miss' seems to be pen/stylus support on many of them.

Comment: sadly, without stylus I cannot insert formulas and such. I could never write tex math as fast as I can scribble it with a pen. I wouldn't want to go back to paper...